# '�' instead normal text from file

Tags: c++, file, multidimensional-array, ifstream, cout

I have file with this code:

```
start:
    var: a , b , c;
    a = 4;
    b = 2;
    c = a + b;
    wuw c;
    end;/
```

I created a class that contains an array of characters in which my code resides:

```
class file{               //class of program file
    private:
    ifstream File;        //file
    char text[X][Y];      //code from file
```

Information from file I load to array using constructor of class:

```
   file(string path)
    {
         File.open(path); //open file

         for(int x = 0 ; x < X ; x++)
         {  
              for (int y = 0; y < Y ; y++) text[x][y] = File.get();     
         }
    }
```

In class I have function that write to console text from array:

```
void write()
{                        
    for (int x = 0 ; x < X ; x++)
    {
         for (int y = 0 ; y < Y ; y++) cout << text[x][y];

    }
}
```

But after calling write() function I have this text:

```
start:
    var: a , b , c;
    a = 4;
    b = 2;

    c = a + b;
    wuw c;
    end;/

������������ 
���������������������������������������� 
���������������������������������������� 
���������������������������������������� 
���������������������������������������� 
����������������������������������������
```

Comment: Off-topic:  You should use a different name the `file` to avoid reader confusion with `FILE *`.  Maybe something like `source_file`.

Comment: Unless your file is exactly 800 characters long you're going to either leave part of your `text` array uninitialized or write past the end of it.

Comment: Do you *need* to read in the entire file before parsing?  In my compiler I wrote, I would input a line at a time and not store the input into a vector.

Comment: Welcome to C++. It's time to use `std::string` plus `std::vector` and abandon C-style character buffers and arrays. One serious problem here is you don't zero out the original array so it could contain junk data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The size of `text` does not correspond to the size of the file. That's not only wasteful, but in this case it's causing you to read off the end of the file. A better design would be to instead define `vector<string> text`. Using a valid `ifstream File` you could populate this `text` in the body of your constructor like this:

```
for(string i; getline(File, i); text.push_back(i));
```

From there, you'd also need to adapt `write` to:

```
copy(cbegin(text), cend(text), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
```

You'd also need to put in safeguard checks that the indices passed into `no_zero` and `ret_char` were valid, but the rest of the code should work as is.

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Dngc8E)

Comment: Basically; write C++ rather than (bad) C. Agreed.